# Compact SVD for $A_{i, j} = \sin(i) \cdot \cos(j)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

We consider matrix $A_{i, j} = \sin(i) \cdot \cos(j)$, $0 \le i, j < n$. It is needed to find the compact SVD for this matrix.

I think the rank is always 1 (for $n > 1$) since each row of this matrix is proportional to the second row but it is not easy to see what is the SVD for this matrix. I understand that for compact SVD I only need to find the first column of $U$ and the first column of $V$. Still don't understand how to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are already given to you. Just take $$a=\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sin^2i},\qquad\qquad b=\sqrt{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\cos^2j},$$
$$
U=\frac1a\begin{bmatrix}\sin 0\\ \vdots\\ \sin(n -1)\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad
 V=\frac1b\begin{bmatrix}\cos 0\\ \vdots\\ \cos(n -1)\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad\Sigma=ab.
$$

Comment: It seems that it is needed to divide both $U$ and $V$ by their length and multiply $\sigma$ by $\|U\| \cdot \|V\|$ because the columns of $U$ and $V$ should be orthonormal.

Comment: Indeed. Edited.